# what can I say about the following kernel estimation?

Tags: estimation, kernel-smoothing

I have a discrete random variable $X$ and two random vectors $\vec{Y}$ and $\vec{Z}$.

For a given $x$ (i.e. an instance of $X$), I am interested in estimating:

$$E[\vec{Y} \vec{Z}^{\top} | X = x]$$

based on samples $(x_1,y_1,z_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n,z_n)$.

I thought of using a kernel estimation method, and estimating the above as:

$$E[\vec{Y} \vec{Z}^{\top} | X = x] \approx \sum_{i=1}^n K(x_i, x) y_i z_i^{\top}.$$

My question is: is there any mention of that in the literature?

I am looking for conditions under which this estimation is "consistent" (i.e. it converges to the true $E[\vec{Y} \vec{Z}^{\top} | X = x],$ and maybe some anchor that I can look for something similar being done.

The closest thing I could find is kernel density estimation, but it is not quite the same.

Comment: It seems to me you may be overcomplicating the situation and that a simple restatement of the problem will point to good solutions. Neither $Y$ nor $Z$ appears in isolation in the problem statement, so you might as well suppose you have collected *bivariate* data $(x_i, u_i)$ where $u_i = y_i\cdot z_i$. In these terms your problem is the general one of regressing $U$ against $X$. This opens up the entire apparatus of regression for application here.

Comment: @whuber may I insist on using kernel estimation for this case? :-) I will revisit the problem again and see if I can do what you suggest, but I definitely want to hear people's opinions about the setting I described.

Comment: @whuber is exactly right. You are trying to find the conditional (on $X_i$) mean of the matrix $\boldsymbol{Y}_i\boldsymbol{Z}_i'$. Writing $\mathbf{U}_i = \boldsymbol{Y}_i\boldsymbol{Z}_i'$, your problem is to estimate $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{U}_i \mid \boldsymbol{X}_i)$, where $\mathbf{U}_i$ is a matrix. Then you can use linear regression, or any other nonparametric method including kernel density estimators in the way that you have set them up -- it is no different from the case where your outcome is a scalar or vector random variable.